# Tag rename: [australian] -> [australian-aboriginal] or [australian-aborigines]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

Currently, the '[australian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian)' tag is used to represent the Australian Aboriginal Dreamtime stories.

However these stories aren't 'Australian' in terms of the current country & the culture introduced by Britain's subsequent settlement. Just as Roman myths and legends are known as [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) and not [italian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italian), they are *unique* to the Aboriginal culture and thus should be tagged as such.

I propose these questions be retagged [australian-aboriginal](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-aboriginal) or [australian-aborigines](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-aborigines).

<sub>'aboriginal' can be used to represent the original peoples of the world over, not just Australian aboriginals, thus it probably shouldn't be a tag to represent just Australian Aborigines by itself</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I can see the reasoning behind this proposed change to the tag. It is a crucially important cultural point that [australian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian) could be construed as been about modern Australian culture, which is quite apart from the [australian-aborigines](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-aborigines).

It is not really possible to make a tag for each Aboriginal Nation, a map of the myriad of Nations (based on language is shown below):

[image]

[Image source](http://www.abc.net.au/indigenous/map/)

An alternative naming of the tag could be [indigenous-australian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indigenous-australian)

Comment: [indigenous-australian] is a much better tag :)

Comment: @Robotnik They're almost universally referred to as (some variation of) Australian Aborigines. I don't think it is a good idea to use a non mainstream name for tags. Rather than unilaterally retagging every question yourself, I think it would be better if you create an answer proposing using [indigenous-australian] and see how the votes stack up.

Comment: @Semaphore - there's three questions. Its not a lot of effort to retag them. All terms are actually [used interchangeably](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Australians), Indigenous Australian seemed to fit better. Besides there's already an answer for indigenous Australian - If you believe its worth retagging, you should create the answer for your suggestion, not the other way around

Comment: @Robotnik The main part of this answer is that we should retag from [australian] to [australian-aboriginal] as you proposed. Upvotes on this answer is not a clear endorsement of the *alternative* suggestion of [indigenous-australian]. That is not, in fact, the same thing as Aboriginal Australian, which is the more standard term.

Answer (score 5):

The Aboriginal Australian people are most commonly referred to as Aboriginal Australians. We should make tags based on the more populist terminology. The term Indigenous Australian is technically correct as well, but normally includes **both** the Aboriginal people and the [Torres Strait Islanders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torres_Strait_Islanders). The latter are [Melanesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanesians) and considered distinct from the mainland Aboriginals.

From Wikipedia:

> The term "Aboriginal" is traditionally applied to only the indigenous inhabitants of mainland Australia and Tasmania, along with some of the adjacent islands, i.e., the "first peoples". Indigenous Australians is an inclusive term used when referring to both Aboriginal and Torres Strait islanders.

I suggest that questions on Aboriginal mythology should use one of [aboriginal-australian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aboriginal-australian) or [australian-aboriginal](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-aboriginal) or [australian-aborigines](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-aborigines), with the others marked as synonyms.

Questions on the mythology of Torres Islanders could either be tagged with their own [torres-islande](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torres-islande), or use a more general[melanesian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melanesian) tag.

The [indigenous-australians](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indigenous-australians) tag could perhaps be used for questions on both groups, or question on general indigenous Australian beliefs without specifying a subgroup (e.g. *does any indigenous Australian group believe that...?*), or possibly a synonym to a main aboriginal tag.