# Should we stop tagging by country?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is related to [Tag rename: [australian] -> [australian-aboriginal] or [australian-aborigines]](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tag-rename-australian-australian-aboriginal-or-australian-aborigines), which I saw just before I posted this.

Currently, we have a number of tags that focus on the mythology of a specific country:

- [chinese](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese)
- [japanese](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese)
- [welsh](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welsh)
- [irish](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish)
- [british](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british)

There are two issues I see with this:

1. A country/region may have vastly different mythologies and religions, making some tags potentially unhelpful.
2. Some mythologies - in fact, many - apply to multiple countries.

As an absurd example, consider Brittany, which happens to have its own tag ([brittany](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brittany)). Brittany is a region in France with strong Celtic culture, comparable to that of the British isles. Technically, a [french](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tag could be used, but the region is, in this sense, quite different from the rest of France.

This is not a common scenario, but it is a valid one. Mythologies are generally not - especially in the case of ancient mythologies - limited to one modern country, and there are often multiple mythologies abundant in one country.

Should we stop tagging by country, or is this issue not a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's not a problem.

Again, the problem with more tags is when they [incite new users to write off topic posts](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/11). If a tag makes the site more searchable, what's the big deal?

Additionally, I usually try hard to put three to five tags in most questions I ask on most Stacks to assist with searching and cross referencing... but on this Stack, I've been struggling. Having tags like these is a good way to have more categories.

Especially a tag like [chinese](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese), which could be about things like Chinese Buddhists or things like early Han mythos, and would certainly assist with questions that perhaps want to ask about the relationship between the two but is more descriptive than [comparative](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative).

Regardless... if a tag becomes a problem later for some reason, it can always be removed.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal would be to

- tag by mythology family first (e.g. [celtic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celtic), [han-china](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/han-china), [ancient-rus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-rus), [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse), [ancient-egyptian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-egyptian)).

  - This neatly takes care of one of the issues you raised, that of multiple mythologies per-country. E.g. if parts of Italy were following Etruscan mythology and parts Roman, you don't tag both with either [italy](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy) or even [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) - you tag the former with ONLY [etruscan](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etruscan) (*unless it's a question of comparative mythology, or etruscan influence on non-Etruscs*).
- If any mythology family strongly corresponds to a single country ([russia](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia)=[ancient-rus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-rus)), we can always add a tag synonym to avoid confusion for new users and simplify life for everyone.
- If on the other hand, we want a narrower mythology for a specific country within a family, we add a country specific tag, BUT, IMPORTANTLY:

  the country in question **has to be achronistic**

  - e.g. [brittany](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brittany) is correct (but should follow a more general [celtic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celtic)), whereas - to the best of my admittedly limited historical knowledge, [france](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france) is incorrect, since at the time that mythology was active, Brittany wasn't yet France.
  - Similar example: you would NOT tag Anatolia or Asia Minor specific questions dealing with Olympian myths with [turkey](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turkey), or [ottoman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ottoman). But you can tag with [anatolia](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatolia).